# py2exe - Create a single exe with all files/resources embedded in the exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I want to create an exe in py2exe with all the files my python program is dependent on and embed them into the exe and still have a single exe with no additional files. How can I do this?

**edit:** py2exe can generate a single executable but it doesn't put the data files in the exe.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because the answers compress the py2exe files but not the data files that the executable requires (examples are images, documents, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named setup.py with the following and place it in the same folder as myscript.py.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sip
setup(options={'py2exe':{'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}}, 
    windows=['myscript.py'], zipfile = None)
```

From a Command Prompt run:

```
setup.py py2exe
```

Comment: What is the 'sip' module for? And, do you have to include the data_files parameter or not?

Comment: You can read about it here: https://pypi.org/project/SIP/  The process will gather all the necessary files.